# change docker instance run arguments

Tags: docker, instance, default-arguments

because our network was blocked by GFW, a firewall, so many sites we cann't access, and our company have a proxy, but unfornatelly, docker can set proxy, but docker instance can't set proxy when it's running, does it have a solution to change instance run arguments on the condition cann't change docker image?

here is the error log

Step 14/14 : RUN core/chaincode/shim/java/javabuild.sh
 ---> Running in dcbf71d7e36a

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':core:chaincode:shim:java'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':core:chaincode:shim:java:classpath'.
  >   Could not download guava.jar (com.google.guava:guava:18.0)
  >   Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0.jar'.
  >   SSL peer shut down incorrectly
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  The command '/bin/sh -c core/chaincode/shim/java/javabuild.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1

Answer (score 0):

the latest docker 1.13 support to set container network while building.
you can set it to --network=host to use host network.
please refer latest docs:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#parent-command